# How to center lightning:select components in a table

Tags: lightning-aura-components, table

I'm trying to center the lightning select and other form elements vertically; how would i do that? would i just have to use an html select and not lightning?

[image]
[image]

```
    <td>
    <div class="slds-p-right_medium slds-p-vertical_xxx-small" >
        <lightning:select aura:id="selectField" name="selectField" label="" 
                          onchange="{!c.fieldSelected}" >
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.fieldWrappers}" var="fieldWrapper">
                <option value="{!fieldWrapper.fieldAPIname}" text="{!fieldWrapper.fieldLabel}"></option>
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:select>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: What do you mean align with other elements? I don't see any problem in your capture.

Comment: @Shuaib Ahmed, I would suggest you review [basic CSS styling tutorials](https://www.w3schools.com/css/) and the [SLDS documentation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/position/) for a better understanding of what you seem to be attempting to do since this is pretty basic CSS stuff, not necessarily Salesforce related.

Comment: I understand how to style basic CSS elements, but the problem is the lightning select wraps the select into a form element that does not vertically center the select.. @martin ,  there's more elements in that row that are vertically centered i'll show in edit - thanks for your help!

Comment: in that case, best include how and what you have tried so far to center your elements, as is, we dont know what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that can be solved by adding the variant.

```
<lightning:select aura:id="selectField" name="selectField" label="" variant="label-hidden" onchange="{!c.fieldSelected}" >
```

The space you see on the top is for the label which is kept as blank. [LINK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_select.htm)

Answer (score 3):

You might need to make use of the STYLE file of the lightning component bundle to overwrite any standard SLDS styles. You need to find the correct CSS tag by **Inspecting Element** on any web browser and apply you new styles in the STYLE file.

Salesforce Developer Blog reference: [Styling with CSS in the Component Bundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/06/styling-css-component-bundle.html)

[CSS in Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_css.htm)

Comment: That's rarely ever needed (e.g. see other answer on this question), but this information is generally useful, as long as you understand it should only be a last resort.

Comment: Yes, this is something we should be considering as a last option. Thanks @sfdcfox for providing your valuable feedback, this makes me feel privileged. :)